# Problem based on Gravitation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation

> A rocket is launched vertically from the surface of the earth with an
>   initial velocity of 10 km/s. How far above the surface of the earth
>   would it go? Radius of the earth = 6400 km; g=9.8 m/s^2.

***Where am I wrong?***

From the Law of Conservation of Energy:

Total energy at earth's surface= Total energy at the topmost point

$$KE_1 + PE_1=KE_2 + PE_2$$

$$\frac{1}{2} m v^2+(-\frac{GMm}{R})=0+(-\frac{GMm}{R+h})$$

M=Mass of the earth

R=Radius of Earth

m=Mass of the Rocket

h=Maximum height reached by the rocket

$v^2=\frac{GM}{R}$

$$\frac{1}{2}\frac{GM}{R}-\frac{GM}{R}=-\frac{GM}{R+h}$$

$$\frac{1}{2R}-\frac{1}{R}=-\frac{1}{R+h}$$

$$h=R$$

Comment: Why do you think that $v^2 = GM/R$?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Oh, I thought the rocket would be orbiting the earth as a satellite. So, if this is not the case, then how should I proceed?

Comment: Please note that this site is not a place to obtain solutions to worked problems. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301) and [this Meta post for "check my work problems"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track when you noted
$$\frac{1}{2}mv^2-\frac{GMm}{R}=-\frac{GMm}{R+h},$$
which can be rearranged to
$$\frac{1}{R+h}=\frac{1}{R}-\frac{v^2}{2GM}=\frac{2GM-v^2R}{2GMR}.$$
Thus
$$h=\frac{2GMR}{2GM-v^2R}-R=\frac{(Rv)^2}{2GM-v^2R}.$$
Now just plug in the given values of all variables.